# vsftpd implicit ftp server

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, ftps

I'm trying to set up ftp server with ftps connection. I need it to test my code that uses bunch other ftp servers who use implicit ssl. So far I didn't manage to set it up. Can't find much useful info on this topic and another problem I have is that I can't see any errors in /var/log/vsftpd.log.

service vsftpd status gives me this:

```
june 11 08:39:40 maks-linux-laptop systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
june 11 08:39:40 maks-linux-laptop systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
june 11 08:39:40 maks-linux-laptop systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
июн 11 08:39:40 maks-linux-laptop systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614097) answer found that I could try start vsftp by running bin file to see the error, but get only this:

```
500 OOPS: run two copies of vsftpd for IPv4 and IPv6
```

Even though my vsftpd service is stopped at this moment.

Here's my **vsftpd.conf** file

```
listen=YES
listen_port=990
listen_ipv6=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
```